# Can any one identify this Right Handed Indexable Blue Bar

Tags: android, android-listview, indexing

Hi there I am seeing this on loads of different apps and am just flustered as to what this is here's a picture of it in BW

[image: mystery widget]

It's just puzzling me as to what it is. I know that it is Blue Barred and can be used to navigate up or down to the page but can any one tell me what this is and a guide on how to use it ?
Also is it possible to achieve this same thing but in a ScrollView with a load of text inside it ?

Comment: That looks like the standard ScrollBar used in ListViews, GridViews, etc for JellyBean.

Comment: ive made a listview app for JellyBean and have never achieved this thing

Comment: Sorry, as Puru has pointed out it's the FastScrollBar, not the regular ScrollBar, but it still is a stock feature so you don't have to do anything complicate to use it.

Answer (score 3):

That BlueBar is called as `FastScrollBar` and it is used for enabling fast scrolling over the `listview`. The bar you are seeing in most of the apps is actually themed version of default FastScrollBar. It can be enabled over a listview by setting `enableFastScroll=true` property of `listview`.
eg.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
```

It will display a thumb over your current scrollbar. You can stylize it using custom drawables   by providing different drawables for its `thumb` and `scrollbar`.

For that you have to set those properties into the style.xml

```
<style name="Theme_app" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>

 </style>
```

Then create an xml in Drawable for the image

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_default_holo" />
</selector>
```

Note that the `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` attribute only applies for Android API Level 11 and later.

Comment: Just have one more question How can I do this inside a text for a Scroll View as this function does not work ?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use the fastScrollBar with the ScrollView. The actual intent behind using fastScrollBar is to let user scroll efficiently and fast through a list containing thousands of list items. Usually a ScrollView can hold any type of view as its children and is mainly used for supporting devices with smaller screen sizes. So I think it doesn't make any sense to use fast scroll bar with them.

Comment: hm ok then so what could I use to achieve this type of blue barred theme?

Comment: you can stylize the Scrollbar for ScrollView by providing custom drawables to it but i don't think implementing the fast scrolling behavior for the case of ScrollView is that easy.